# Mount Etna: from Nicolosi to Rifugio Sapienza on foot?

Tags: italy, walking, mountains, trekking, sicily

I will visit soon the north-east of **Sicily** (provinces of **Catania** and Messina).

I would like to know if there is any pedestrian trail starting from the town of [**Nicolosi (CT)**](https://goo.gl/maps/7f2bomGwRhNqpRYP6) and leading to the lodge known as [**Rifugio Giovanni Sapienza**](https://g.page/rifugio-sapienza?share) on **Mount Etna**, or any way to reach the latter from the former by just trekking.

I can't find any documentation about this specifically and my impression is that, if this one was a pedestrian itinerary it would be mentioned somewhere. I am aware of a bus connecting the two places, for excursions to start *from* Rifugio Sapienza. Two roads connect Nicolosi to Rifugio Sapienza ([SP92](https://goo.gl/maps/JhzRc3mj5sFckojE9) and [via Catania](https://goo.gl/maps/g2zXKswgftz5ePh56)) but both of them only seem to be an option by car.

I am collecting several info online but I have never used any specific app for trekking trails...including this time. Thanks in advance for any relevant information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a trail, the Sentiero Silvestri number 789.

https://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/#route?id=8461974

Comment: You were [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7bR3.jpg)!! Thank you, very very beautiful trail by the way :)